# how to execute two for loops simultaneously in java without useing multithreading

Tags: java

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
  }
  for(int j=5;j>0;j--) {
        System.out.print(j+" ");
  }
```

=> for this I got this output:`-1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1`

=> but I need like this output:`-1 5 2 4 3 3 4 2 5 1`

Comment: you could define 2 variables in side 1 for loop and get this output, if that'w what you're asking

Comment: Just as a sidenote: Using `multithreading` here would not give you the result you are asking for. Just because you seem to think that would be a potential solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge 2 for-statements.

```
for (int i = 1, j = 5; i <= 5; i++, j--) {
    System.out.print(i + " " + j + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in a single loop.

```
int len = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++)
{
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    System.out.print(len - (i - 1) + " ");
}
```